# Emacs being laggy and creating 0 byte files in working directory

Tags: emacs

I've Emacs setup for Verilog, SystemVerilog and UVM.
I use auto-complete, solarize theme and verilog-mode as add-ons.

I need to work on C once in a while, however with C Emacs feels very laggy (takes a while for auto-complete suggestions) and it creates bunch of 0 byte files in my working directory (with names containing symbols -- not letters).

I'm not sure about the cause or how to debug and solve the issue. I would appreciate if someone can help me with finding and solving this issue.

[EDIT]: I understand this can be lacking in information, however right now I'm not sure what type of information I should be providing, I will provide information as required

[EDIT2]: 
I've commented following portion of init file and my c editing is working well, What part of loading auto-complete can cause these?
The problems I was facing:
1. Creating random symbol files with 0 bytes of size in working directory (name would look like ?/??UR...)
2. Laggy: takes a while for character to show up when typed

```
;; This section is required to enable autocomplete and verilog dictionary
;;(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/user/.emacs.d/")
;;(require 'auto-complete-config)
;;(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "/home/user/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
;;(ac-config-default)

;;ac-modes - mojor modes ac can run on
;;(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'verilog-mode 'c-mode)

;;toggle auto complete in all buffers
;;(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

Answer (score 1):

*I understand this can be lacking in information, however right now I'm not sure what type of information I should be providing, I will provide information as required*

That's the right attitude, and yes, you sensed correctly that the problem description is currently too broad for people to be able to help (unless you are lucky and find someone who recognizes the same combination of setups etc.).

The first step is to isolate the cause of the problem, at least to one (instead of 3) feature that you are using. IOW, break down your "setup for Verilog, SystemVerilog and UVM" which uses "auto-complete, solarize theme and verilog-mode as add-ons", so that you can report that the problem is only in using, say, auto-complete. Or is only in the combination of, say, theme solarize with verilog-mode.

IOW, at the highest level this is no different from any other debugging scenario.

As it stands now, you are, in effect, telling us that you have this big sack of stuff and you want someone to guess what is going on.

To narrow the problem, recursively bisect your init file, commenting out bigger and bigger chunks, until you know what part(s) of it are really causing the problem.  Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8,... You can use command `comment-region` to comment or (with prefix arg `C-u`) uncommment the selected text.

Once you have a better idea of what is causing the problem, report back here with the refined problem statement and the additional info you've learned.

At that point you will also want to specify what you mean by this or that being "laggy". You will hopefully be able to give others a recipe to reproduce the effect you see, and you will be able to describe better what you expected to see, but didn't.

Comment: Thanks, I tried commenting each  mode and it seems auto-complete mode is causing the issue (Updating original question)